# Passing Values to a Textfield from another ASP Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a page which show the count of the members in a textfield. And a second page where i can add members in a list. 
i saved the count of the member from the second page in an integer but how can i transfer it to the first page to show the result in a textfield?

the second page is in a frame from the first page.

i hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Session State to transfer variables to another page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx